# Unable to use pg_ctl in Windows CMD?

Tags: postgresql, cmd, database-administration

```
pg_ctl status
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.

C:\Users\Think>pg_ctl --help
pg_ctl is a utility to initialize, start, stop, or control a PostgreSQL server.
```

I don't know where is the pg_data directory, I set the C:\Users\Think\Desktop\postgres\data as **User variable** and **System Variable** In windows setting.
But still not working.
In the **bin** directory, there is pg_ctl.exe file.

[image: Enviroment Variable]

Comment: Have you ever read the documentation of [pg-ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pg-ctl.html) or of [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/) at all or have you thought reading documentations is a waste of time as you can ask others how to use PostgreSQL and its applications?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `-D` option to tell `pg_ctl` where your data directory is:

```sh
pg_ctl -D "Q:\path\to\datadir"
```

If you have created a data directory, you should be able to find it in `cmd.exe` with

```sh
dir C:\ /s /b | find PG_VERSION
```

if it is on `C:`.

If you just clicked through the installer, it might be in

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data
```

Answer (score -1):

use pg_ctl using the bin directory path of postgresql. Like root/.../../postgresql/bin/pg_ctl <then your command for restart, etc>

Comment: This is *not* about finding the `pg_ctl` executable.